# Simple, standalone (i.e., no external files), offline, client-based solution for selecting file and displaying contents in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, offlineapps, client-side-data

I'd sum this up as looking for an offline client solution that is 100% standalone and uses no external files/libraries or other machine resources to tabulate data from a user-chosen TSV file (the result is simply rendered in a plain HTML table - nothing fancy, just data).

I am not a web programmer, but have volunteered to do this project. I have been asked to code this as a browser-based solution because the party deems it the most user-friendly for their needs.

Again, this is not an html file that is served; it is emailed to a client that copies it into a folder of their choosing and run (by selecting a local file to render).

Every time I attempt some solution (e.g., FileReader, etc.), I can only get it to only work in a certain manner with specific browsers (including having to use it differently in the same code depending upon the browser - is this simply my lack of knowledge?).

My question is: Is there one single way to code this for most browsers (including older browsers like IE8)?

If not, I would most appreciate suggestions - both general and specific.
An example would be helpful if possible.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are not a programmer and are asked to code you will naturally struggle to find solutions. Your best bet it to go to one of the free sites online and start learning. Here are a few you might try: Code School, Code Academy, Udemy, Coursera.

Comment: I am a programmer, just in a different paradigm that don't change as frequently as the last time I had to teach myself this. I have been reading and searching. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I am minimally adept with a number of languages that could perform this task and quite comfortable on a server. I advised against using the browser, but that's the only thing they wanted. Thanks everyone for the quick input. Still looking around and tending in the FileReader as a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for client/browser specific, you won't have access to the file system.    That's a security breach that isn't implemented into the browsers.   You're going to *need* to implement some sort of server-side technology to take a crack at the file being handed over, or you will need to strictly specify which browsers are supported (things like FileReader are only IE10 or better).

I've never tried using the INPUT FILE to see if it will load a file before pushing it to the server (in say a FORM POST or a XHR/AJAX push)-  but maybe look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Let's see -- what else.    If the file has a specific name, your HTML could reference it in an IFRAME and see if you can't communicate back and forth between the IFRAME and the parent window.

You're really limiting yourself without having a server being able to process it, and the browser range you need.    Your best bet might be the File API and restrict the lower limit of browser compatibility?

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: I know it's possible to do this (or was), because I did something similar a few years ago, but this was before Chrome existed, before FileReader, etc. At the time of the original posting, FileReader is what I'm attempting (with the assumption that older browsers might have to be all handled separately). Thanks so much.

Comment: In the wake of cross-site scripting attacks, and vulnerabilities in IE ActiveX -- all browsers operate in a sandbox model, that don't give the HTML/JS code access to the underlying file or operating system structure.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this for all browsers. Especially for IE8. If you need a standalone application, the best way is to use C++/Java/C# or any language that allows to create desctop applications.